# Icon to represent a music artist in a music app?

Tags: icon, representation

I'm building the interface for a music application and you can sort by songs, albums, artists, etc. I have icons for all of these, but I'm currently using a generic "person" icon for artists/musicians. What icon can be used to represent "music artist"?

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this represented by an outline of an artist holding a mic. Depending on what your userbase will be like, you could have more fun with it, like maybe an outline of someone holding a guitar, a concert pianist, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use of 2 different icon for musician and music artist will be a good option, you can design something like this.

[image]

Comment: I like your first one but I'd like to clarify that I don't need a separate icon for musicians; that was just to give a synonym for artist.

Comment: In my opinion, in that case you may use the second one.
As I feel mic is most suitable for a vocal artist. While a musical note can represent both.

Comment: Good point. Any other secondary icons that may fit as well?

Comment: If the dimensions is not big enough, you may remove user pic and try to do a mix of both mic and music note.

Answer (score 1):

You could somehow add a microphone to the icon, or notes maybe a portion of a music score.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for inspiration: http://thenounproject.com/search/?q=musician 
One of my favourite icon collections website =)
 They have huge amount of ideas for different icons =)